# Access Oracle Table from Sql Server

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008

I have two different databases, one is in sql server and one is in oracle. i create a linked server between those two. how can i get data from oracle without the option "openquery".

Please help me out this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a connection link in oracle and then you can access the sql server database
see:  [Oracle connection link](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_admin002.htm)